# What has happened with the "Steward" badge?

Tags: support, bug

I got all of them a second time a couple of minutes ago.

Comment: See [Steward badges being re-awarded suddenly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360194)

Comment: And [Steward badge can now be awarded multiple times -- backfill details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360279)

Comment: Hm... I don't think it is a good idea, but this is the answer.

Comment: But why didn't I get 20 badges for the Close votes queue then? :-))))))

Comment: "The backfill script will run about twice an hour, and your achievements trophy will light up as each one is awarded."

Comment: Are you serious? Is it really supposed to give 20 badges? It is a nonsense.

Comment: Hm, it really does give badges all the time

Comment: I now have 50 gold badges o.O

Comment: @Zanna I have 65 ))))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, [the Steward badge can now be awarded multiple times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360279/steward-badge-can-now-be-awarded-multiple-times-backfill-details), and they have been retroactively awarded.

Maybe review participation (or at least *my* review participation) will improve :)